# How to show "CREATE TABLE" for existing table?

Tags: firebird

In MySQL, there's SQL statement to show the "CREATE TABLE" statement for existed tables

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE `mytable`;
```

what is the equivalent of SQL statement for Firebird 2.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no equivalent statement in Firebird itself. Various tools provide features to reverse engineer the `CREATE TABLE` statement from the metadata of the database.

For example, in ISQL (the commandline query tool included in Firebird), you can use commandline option `-extract` (or `-ex` for short) to generate the DDL of the entire database, but you can't extract a single table.

```bash
isql -extract -user sysdba -password <your password> localhost:<database>
```

Other Firebird-specific tools have similar options, and usually support extracting individual objects. For example, in FlameRobin, you can right click on a database object, *Generate code*, *Extract full DDL for <objectname>*, or double click or right click, *Properties* on an object and view the DDL in the *DDL* tab of the properties.